# CallableStatement executeQuery return resultSet but execute return false

Tags: java, sql-server

My stored procedure should return a string like the following

```
BEGIN TRY     
   .....  
   PRINT 'COMMIT';
   select '';
   COMMIT TRANSACTION MYTRAN; 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH     
    PRINT 'ROLLBACK';
    select CONCAT('',ERROR_NUMBER(),',',ERROR_LINE(),',',ERROR_MESSAGE());
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MYTRAN;        
END CATCH;
```

1. If I call my stored procedure using callablestatement.executeQuery, resultset is returned, but if I call my stored procedure using callablestatement.execute, return false, why?
2. callablestatement.execute return getUpdateCount() return 1, then how to retrieve the string returned?

[image]

Comment: Is this for SQL Server?

Comment: yes, for sql server